# Angular Router.url not return updated path

Tags: angular, components

I have defined such component:
header.component.html

```
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark sticky-top shado">
   <a routerLink='/'  class="navbar-brand" (click)="onClick()" >
      <img [src]=logo alt="Logo" style="width:40px;">
         {{ logoName }}
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span> 
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
     <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 nav-justified" >
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let nav of navbars" (click)="onClick()"  >
           <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]=nav.routerlink>
              {{ nav.name }}
           </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

headers.component.ts

```
export class HeadersComponent implements OnInit {
  navbars = [{ name : 'Datos Generales',     routerlink : 'datosgenerales'},
             { name : 'Plan de  Enseñanza',  routerlink : 'planensenanza'},
             { name : 'Plan de Aprendizaje', routerlink : 'planaprendizaje'},
             { name : 'Plan Tutorial',       routerlink : '#'},
             { name : 'Bibliografia',        routerlink : '#'}];

  constructor(private route: Router ) {
   }

  onClick(){
    console.log('URL is ' + this.route.url);
  }
}
```

[image]

when I click in the "Plan de Aprendizaje"
link in web is set to => http://localhost:4200/planaprendizaje
console print  URL is /aprendizaje

However if i click to the logo symbol ULPGC to go home
link in web is set to => http://localhost:4200
but console print  URL still is /aprendizaje

I need to get the current URL but when clicking in the path to home the route url is not updated. I need to click again to get the correct path

path route configuration

```
 { path: '', component: SignInComponent },
  { path: 'datosgenerales',  component: DatosGeneralesComponent },
  { path: 'planensenanza',   component: PlanEnsenanzaComponent },
  { path: 'planaprendizaje', component: PlanAprendizajeComponent }
```

Any idea what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: yes, I have tried with Router.snapshot['_routerState'].url but got the same